# Set as NA specific columns in multi-layer terra objects

Tags: r, raster, terra

Given:

```
library(terra)
r <- rast(nrows=512, ncols=640,nlyrs=1, res=1,crs="local",extent=c(0,640,0,512))
values(r) <- rnorm(ncell(r),100,10)
x <- c(r, r*2, r*3, r*0.5)
plotRGB(x, stretch="lin")
```

and

```
weirds <- data.frame(bands=c(1,3), mincol=c(5,100), maxcol=c(7,103))
weirds
> weirds
  bands mincol maxcol
     1      5      7
     3    100    103
```

I have to set as NA those cells within *mincol* and *maxcol* in *weirds* for the given *bands*.
I achieve in this way:

```
y <- x
for (i in 1:nrow(weirds)) {
  y[[weirds$bands[i]]][,weirds$mincol[i]:weirds$maxcol[i]]  <- NA
}
plotRGB(y, stretch="lin")
```

But I am sure there are more efficient ways. Can anyone make suggestions?

Comment: Is there any example data or desired output that could be given here? I'm not familiar with the package but this should be relatively straightforward, although it is hard to figure out what is going on as is.

Comment: your code doesn't run. `r <- rast(nrows=512, ncols=640,nlyrs=1, res=1,crs="local",extent=c(0,640,0,512))
Error: [rast] empty srs`

Comment: @langtang have you loaded terra? It does run for me with  terra 1.6-20. Perhaps the use of crs="local" has not made to the version on CRAN yet. Try with r <- rast(nrows=512, ncols=640,nlyrs=1, res=1,crs="",extent=c(0,640,0,512))

Comment: @diomedesdata: I do provide a reproducible example and the exact output I want. What I request is a more efficient way of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With terra 1.6-24 (currently the development version) you can use indexing for layers.

Example data

```
library(terra)
#terra 1.6.24
r <- rast(nrows=30, ncols=30, nlyrs=1,extent=c(0,640,0,512))
values(r) <- rnorm(ncell(r), 100, 10)
x <- c(r, r*2, r*3)
w <- data.frame(bands=c(1,3), mincol=c(5,20), maxcol=c(7,23))
```

First approach. This is very similar to what you had, but perhaps a little cleaner.

```
y <- x
for (i in 1:nrow(w)) {
  y[ , w$mincol[i]:w$maxcol[i], w$bands[i]] <- NA
}
plot(y)
```

Second approach. Using a list for one or more of the indices `i` (row), `j` (col), or `k` (lyr) you can do multiple replacements at once.

```
z <- x
cols <- lapply(1:nrow(w), function(i) seq(w[i, 2], w[i, 3]))
z[ , cols, w$bands] <- NA
plot(z, nc=3)
```

[image]

I would assume that this is the better approach and that you can probably directly create the `cols` list, instead of deriving it from `w`

You can install the development version of "terra" with `install.packages('terra', repos='https://rspatial.r-universe.dev')`